# Specify the color of a SVG image in .NET Maui

Tags: xaml, maui

.NET MAUI has the ability to use SVG images which is really nice, but I haven't been able to set the color of the SVG image. The official docs state I could use the TintColor in the project file but that's not a good solution as I want to be able to use different colors depending on certain conditions. So can we somehow specify the color of a SVG image?

Comment: Just use https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls for Android and iOS, uses SkiaSharp to display SVG on the canvas thereby not converting it into PNG so you don't have to use hacks like the TintColor Behavior

Answer (score 25):

I just figured out that the [Maui Community toolkit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.Maui) has a `IconTintColorBehavior` that does just want I want.

Usage:

```
<Image Source="shield.png">
    <Image.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:IconTintColorBehavior TintColor="Red" />
    </Image.Behaviors>
</Image>
```

---

namespace

```
xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
```

Comment: The IconTintColorBehavior is not supported on Windows according to their [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/icon-tint-color-behavior)

Comment: Support is now added for Windows as well :-)

Comment: what is the namespace?

Comment: @Jasper Can you remember how you added the conitional into the mix here. The OP mentioned 'certain conditions'.

Comment: @tonyedwardspz IconTintColorBehaviour has a BindableProperty TintColor. In the exemple Jasper used the color Red but it can be any binding you like. You can also use converters.

Comment: @CodeMylife I spotted that, but failed to combine it with a convertor from the toolkit. I'd welcome a second pair of eyes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77964649/combining-booltoobjectconvertor-and-icontint

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use **skiasharp**. I give some examples.

First add Nuget, such as SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Controls, SkiaSharp.Svg.

In the xaml, define a SKCanvasView. The PaintSurface event handler is where you do all your drawing.

```
<StackLayout>
    <skiact:SKCanvasView  WidthRequest="500" HeightRequest="500" x:Name="mycanvasview" PaintSurface="mycanvasview_PaintSurface">
    </skiact:SKCanvasView>
</StackLayout>
```

In the .cs file, implement **mycanvasview_PaintSurface** method. Add some code like this:

```
private void mycanvasview_PaintSurface(object sender, SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
{
    SKImageInfo info = e.Info;
    SKSurface surface = e.Surface;
    SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

    canvas.Clear();
    Stream stream = LoadStream(typeof(MainPage),"myfile.svg");
    SKSvg svg = new SKSvg();
    svg.Load(stream);

    using (var paint = new SKPaint())
    {
        paint.ColorFilter = SKColorFilter.CreateBlendMode(
            SKColors.Yellow,      
            SKBlendMode.SrcIn); 
        canvas.DrawPicture(svg.Picture ,paint);
    }
}


private static Stream LoadStream(Type type, string v)
{
    Assembly assembly = type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
    Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(v);
    return stream;
}
```

You svg file will change the color.

I hope my answer could help you.

Comment: Or you could check my comment on the question

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a cross-platform vector file format that .NET MAUI natively supports and you are willing to pre-convert, then, consider converting your SVG icons assets to a TTF (true-type font). TTF will keep your icons in vector format and they can be resized and recolored at runtime.

1. Convert your SVGs into a single TTF
2. Add the TTF to your .NET MAUI application's resource
3. Add it to the MauiProgram.cs ConfigureFonts
4. Use the font directly in XAML Label or FontImageSource

Here are detailed steps on how to do the above.

### 1. Convert your SVGs into a single TTF

Install Node.JS / NPM package https://www.npmjs.com/package/fantasticon :

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install npm
sudo npm install -g fantasticon
```

Prepare a conversion workspace:

```
maui-svg-ttf/scripts/svg/compass.svg
maui-svg-ttf/scripts/svg/globe.svg
maui-svg-ttf/scripts/svg/locator.svg
maui-svg-ttf/scripts/svg/shield.svg
maui-svg-ttf/scripts/makefonts.sh
maui-svg-ttf/scripts/my-icons.js
```

Here's `makefonts.sh`:

```bash
mkdir -p /tmp/maui-svg-ttf
fantasticon --config my-icons.js
cp /tmp/maui-svg-ttf/my-icons.ttf ../Resources/fonts/my-icons.ttf
```

Here's `my-icons.js`:

```bash
module.exports = {
    name: 'my-icons',
    fontHeight: 500,
    normalize: true,
    inputDir: 'svg',
    outputDir: '/tmp/maui-svg-ttf',
    fontTypes: ['ttf'],
    assetTypes: ['css', 'json', 'html'],
    formatOptions: {
        json: {
            indent: 2
        }
    },
    codepoints: {
        'globe'   : 0xe000, // globe.svg   at 0xe000 codepoint
        'compass' : 0x0001, // compass.svg at 0x0001 codepoint
        'locator' : 0x0002, // locator.svg at 0x0002 codepoint
        'shield'  : 0xe003, // shield.svg  at 0xe003 codepoint
    },
    getIconId: ({
        basename, // `string` - Example: 'foo';
        relativeDirPath, // `string` - Example: 'sub/dir/foo.svg'
        absoluteFilePath, // `string` - Example: '/var/icons/sub/dir/foo.svg'
        relativeFilePath, // `string` - Example: 'foo.svg'
        index // `number` - Example: `0`
    }) => {
        return basename;
    }
};
```

### 2. Add the TTF to your .NET MAUI application's resource

Make sure your new font `my-icons.ttf` gets copied to your `Resources/fonts/` folder.

### 3. Add it to the MauiProgram.cs ConfigureFonts

```cs
// MauiProgram.cs ...
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
builder
    .UseMauiApp<App>()
    .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
    {
        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
        fonts.AddFont("my-icons.ttf", "my-icons");
    });
builder.Services.AddTransient<MainViewModel>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<MainPage>();
```

### 4. Use the font directly in XAML Label or FontImageSource

```xml
<VerticalStackLayout>
    <Label Text="&#xe000;" FontFamily="my-icons" FontSize="{Binding IconSize}" TextColor="{Binding Color}" Rotation="{Binding Angle}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
    <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <Image HeightRequest="{Binding IconSize}" WidthRequest="{Binding IconSize}" Rotation="{Binding Angle}">
            <Image.Source>
                <FontImageSource Glyph="&#xe001;" FontFamily="my-icons" Color="{Binding Color}" Size="{Binding IconSize}"  />
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
        <Image HeightRequest="{Binding IconSize}" WidthRequest="{Binding IconSize}" Rotation="{Binding Angle}">
            <Image.Source>
                <FontImageSource Glyph="&#xe002;" FontFamily="my-icons" Color="{Binding Color}" Size="{Binding IconSize}"  />
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
        <Image HeightRequest="{Binding IconSize}" WidthRequest="{Binding IconSize}" Rotation="{Binding Angle}">
            <Image.Source>
                <FontImageSource Glyph="&#xe003;" FontFamily="my-icons" Color="{Binding Color}" Size="{Binding IconSize}" />
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
    <Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="255" Value="{Binding RedValue, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="255" Value="{Binding GreenValue, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="255" Value="{Binding BlueValue, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <Slider Minimum="32" Maximum="80" Value="{Binding IconSize, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="360" Value="{Binding Angle, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

```cs
// MainPage.xaml.cs ...
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage(MainViewModel VM)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = VM;
    }
}
```

```cs
// MainViewModel.cs ...
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Color))]
    int _redValue = 128;

    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Color))]
    int _greenValue = 0;

    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(Color))]
    int _blueValue = 0;

    [ObservableProperty]
    int _iconSize = 32;

    [ObservableProperty]
    int _angle = 0;

    public Color Color => Color.FromRgb(RedValue, GreenValue, BlueValue);
}
```

[image: SVGtoTTF-New.gif]

Full source code for the above: https://github.com/stephenquan/maui-svg-ttf

Comment: A lot of useful knowledge, all at one place.