# Tinting the color of a svg image in .NET Maui

Tags: xaml, svg, xamarin.forms, maui, maui-community-toolkit

I am trying to dynamically tint the color of a svg image in .NET Maui as I am transitioning from Xamarin.Forms. I have the following code set up to use a binding to a color in string format, but I am getting the following error thrown. Any ideas on how to achieve this in .NET Maui?

Error   XLS0503 A value of type 'IconTintColorBehavior' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'IList`1'

XAML Code

```
<Grid>
    <Image
    x:Name="NeedleSVG"
    WidthRequest="200"
    HeightRequest="200"
    Source="resource://XamarinAttributeProgrammer.Resources.Images.Needle.svg">
        <Image.Effects>
            <mct:IconTintColorBehavior TintColor="{Binding NeedleColorInHex}" />
        </Image.Effects>
    </Image>

    <Image
    WidthRequest="200"
    HeightRequest="200"
    Source="resource://XamarinAttributeProgrammer.Resources.Images.Backlight.svg">
        <Image.Effects>
            <mct:IconTintColorBehavior TintColor="{Binding BackColorInHex}" />
        </Image.Effects>
    </Image>

    <Image
    WidthRequest="200"
    HeightRequest="200"
    Source="resource://XamarinAttributeProgrammer.Resources.Images.Housing.svg">
        <Image.Effects>
            <mct:IconTintColorBehavior TintColor="{Binding BackColorInHex}" />
        </Image.Effects>
    </Image>
    <Button ClassId="BackLight" 
            BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
            WidthRequest="250" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" 
            Clicked="OnPreviewTapped"/>
    <Button ClassId="Needle" 
            BackgroundColor="Transparent" 
            HeightRequest="80" 
            WidthRequest="80" 
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" 
            Margin="0,20,0,0" 
            Clicked="OnPreviewTapped"/>
</Grid>
```

View Model

```
public string SelectedColorInHex
{
    get
    {
        NotifyGaugeOfChangeAsync();
        Task.Delay(50).Wait(); // wait 50ms so that we dont flood the gauge
        if (FocusColorOn == BACKLIGHT)
            return BackColorInHex;
        else
            return NeedleColorInHex;
    }
    set
    {
        if (FocusColorOn == BACKLIGHT)
            _colorBack.Hex = value;
        else
            _colorNeedle.Hex = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use .png, when trying to reference images, not .svg.

Comment: How about converting them to TTF then you can easily recolor them. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77429861/881441

Answer (score 5):

you are trying to add a **behavior** to the **effects** collection

```
<Image.Effects>
    <mct:IconTintColorBehavior TintColor="{Binding NeedleColorInHex}" />
</Image.Effects>
```

should be

```
<Image.Behaviors>
    <mct:IconTintColorBehavior TintColor="{Binding NeedleColorInHex}" />
</Image.Behaviors>
```