# Change SVG color in MAUI for Android

Tags: c#, android, image, svg, maui

Ey guys what's up? Im a noob and I have trying to make an app that change the svg color using RGB sliders to mix, but I dont know how to make it to works, that is the app (I dont need help to create a color or mix color, only need to know how apply the color to the svg):

[Screenshot of sliders and svg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ih8Pq.png)

The image I want to change color:

```
<Image
    Source="color.svg"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="1"/>
```

The sliders (I know how create a color in C# using 255 value of each slider whit Color.FromRgb()):

```
<!-- Only red but I have all 3 done -->
<Slider
    x:Name="sldRed"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="2"
    WidthRequest="255"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    Maximum="255"
    Minimum="0"
    Value="{Binding RedValue, Mode=TwoWay}"/> <!-- Binding to red RGB value-->
<Entry
    x:Name="entRed"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="3"
    HeightRequest="35"
    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    HorizontalOptions="Start"
    Keyboard="Numeric"
    FontFamily="QR"
    FontSize="Body"
    TextColor="{StaticResource Active}"
    Text="{Binding RedValue, Mode=TwoWay}"/> <!-- Binding to red RGB value-->
```

Code behind:

```
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        private int _redValue;
        private int _greenValue;
        private int _blueValue;
        public int RedValue
        {
            get => _redValue;
            set
            {
                if (_redValue != value)
                {
                    if (value < 0) _redValue = 0;
                    else if (value > 255) _redValue = 255;
                    _redValue = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(RedValue));
                }
            }
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = this;
        }
    }
```

Any idea?

I have tried

```
<Image Source="shield.png">
<Image.Behaviors>
<toolkit:IconTintColorBehavior TintColor="Red" />
</Image.Behaviors>
</Image>
```

I want the color the app makes using RGB values change the color.svg color, to show the color maked

Comment: you have to bind the `TintColor` property to a property in your VM

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334591/specify-the-color-of-a-svg-image-in-net-maui

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution (only if you want colorize all svg at once):

- Go to project/Manage NuGet packages...
- Search and install CommunityToolkit.Maui (not core version)
- At MauiProgram.cs, add the line .UseMauiCommunityToolkit() after .UseMauiApp() and before .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>, you will get some loke this:

  ```
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    builder
        .UseMauiApp<App>()
        .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
        .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
        {
            fonts.AddFont("Quicksand-Regular", "QR");
            fonts.AddFont("Quicksand-Light", "QL");
            fonts.AddFont("Quicksand-Bold", "QB");
        });
  ```
- At your XAML file add xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit" at the top, you get some like this:

  ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
  x:Class="RGBee.MainPage"
  xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit">
- At your image add Image.Behaviors:

  ```
    <Image
        Source="color.png"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="1">
        <Image.Behaviors>
            <toolkit:IconTintColorBehavior TintColor="#FFFF00"/>
        </Image.Behaviors>
    </Image>
  ```

voila!

Comment: this doesn't seem to address the question you asked