# Convert SVG to drawable/canvas for GraphicsView in .NET MAUI app

Tags: c#, svg, graphics, maui, drawable

Is there a way to convert SVG vector files, or any vector illustration format, into actual drawables for a `GraphicsView` in my .NET MAUI application?

This is an example of the code I'd like to end up with, in case of a simple rectangle. Though some of the illustrations can have multiple colors and elements:

```
canvas.StrokeColor = Colors.DarkBlue;
canvas.StrokeSize = 4;
canvas.DrawRectangle(10, 10, 100, 50);
```

I would like to input an SVG file somewhere to receive the code for a `canvas` object to use in my application. Main goal is getting rid of the SVG files entirely so I only have some code to deal with in my program. Perhaps changing a few colors or anchor points using the position parameters of the `DrawRectangle()` for example. [ShapeShifter](https://shapeshifter.design/) does something similar but it converts any SVG into an XML file, mainly for use in Android.

Comment: Do you need to do this at runtime or can they be converted at build time?  MAUI will automatically convert SVG to PNG when files are added to the project

Comment: @Jason It does not have to be at runtime. I would like to convert my SVG file to code for a `canvas` so I don't need the file anymore.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/curves/path-data

Comment: Would it help to convert your SVG to a TTF? In TTF format, the geometry stays as vectors and can be resized and recolored. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77429861/881441

Comment: @StephenQuan It does come close, but I suppose the more complex operations that I'm actually looking for (having multiple colors in an illustration, or changing an anchor point position) may not be possible.