# Combining BoolToObjectConvertor and IconTint

Tags: maui, maui-community-toolkit

I'm trying to set the color of an icon depending on a boolean. When `opened = true`, the icon should be black, and when `opened == false`, it should be red. With the code below, it's displaying as the dotnet purple as set within the SVG.

To achieve this, I'm trying to combine IconTintColor and BoolToObjectConverter from the Maui Community Toolkit. The icon tint is setup and working correctly, as setting the color directly via TintColor within the image tag works as expected.

The setup for the bool to object convertor:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
        <Color x:Key="TrueColor">Black</Color>
        <Color x:Key="FalseColor">Red</Color>
        <toolkit:BoolToObjectConverter x:Key="BoolToColorConverter" 
                                       TrueObject="{StaticResource TrueColor}" 
                                       FalseObject="{StaticResource FalseColor}" />
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

Similarly, this doesn't work either:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
        <toolkit:BoolToObjectConverter x:Key="BoolToColorConverter" 
                                       TrueObject="Black" 
                                       FalseObject="Red" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>
```

The usage in the image tag, which sits within a collection view:

```
<Image 
    Source="icon_my_notifications.png"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="0"">
    <Image.Behaviors>
        <toolkit:IconTintColorBehavior 
            TintColor="{Binding opened, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}}" />
    </Image.Behaviors>
</Image>
```

- The source image is an svg.
- Opened is set to a mixture of True/False, and confirmed present from the view model
- Other values from the object are used else where within the collection view

A simplified version of the SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 11.95 7.11">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: #3b383a;
        stroke-width: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
    <path class="cls-1" d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Happy to add more code if needed and relevant. Thanks in advance for any help / points in the right direction.

Comment: Your question seems to be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74334591/specify-the-color-of-a-svg-image-in-net-maui - your BoolToObjectConverter looks fine. The problem is the IconTintColorBehavior and that's really subject to any colors specified in your original SVG.

Comment: @StephenQuan Thanks. I saw that one, and have those fixes in my back pocket. The OP there ended up using icon tint behaviour as I have, but didn't add the conditinal part related the the question :( I'm hoping I'm missing some MAUI magic somewhere. I might be missing some nuance in your sentence "that's really subject to any colors specified in your original SVG."???

Comment: Your question would be helpful if (1) you supplied your SVG, (2) or, at least, a minimal SVG that can repro the problem - a simple geometry will do, such as a line, a square, a triangle or a circle.

Comment: A very simple solution to the problem would be to get rid of `BoolToObjectConverter` and the `IconTintColorBehavior`, and, instead supply two versions of your SVG with a hashed name, such as `icon_my_notifications_true.svg` and `icon_my_notifications_false.svg`. And bind your Image source to `"{Binding opened, StringFormat='icon_my_notifications_{0}.png'}"`

Comment: I've added the SVG code. Love the simplified solution, and that's jumped to the top of the backup list.

Ideally, I'd use the icon tint. It feels like this should work given that I can replace the reference to the convertor with a string color and it works.

Comment: Hey @StephenQuan. I never found a solution to this, and ended up using your suggestion. If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it. . . until an answer closer to my original code turns up. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, a simpler approach would be to use two versions of your SVG with a hashed name, such as `icon_my_notifications_true.svg` and `icon_my_notifications_false.svg`. Then you can bind directly with

```xml
<Image 
    Source="{Binding opened, StringFormat='icon_my_notifications_{0}.png'}" 
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="0" />
```